# How to Create Spring Boot Thin and Fat Jar in Same Spring Boot Maven Project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am having a need to build my spring boot project as both fat and thin jar,

Expected output: one fat jar and one thin jar

Actual output: both are fat jars. I extracted and checked, it contains BOOT-INF/lib having jars

Following is my build plugin configuration

```
spring boot version 2.4.3
spring boot thin version 1.0.25.RELEASE
```

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-fat-jar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.mycomp.ExampleApplication</mainClass>
                        <addResources>true</addResources>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-fat-${project.version}</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-thin-jar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>false</executable>
                        <addResources>true</addResources>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-thin-${project.version}</finalName>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                                <version>${springboot.thin.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sping boot mvn already creates a fat and thin jars by default

```
target/myapp-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar             <- fat
target/myapp-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.original    <- thin
```

So all you need to do is extract the dependencies

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

into `target/lib/*` then change the way you invoke the spring boot app:

- Old invocation was `java -jar target/myapp-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
- New invocation is `java -cp target/myapp-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.original:target/lib/* com.whatever.myapp.Application`

Answer (score 0):

There is an experimental thin layout project from Spring, try to use the below and it will help you.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.28.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher

Answer (score 0):

I think creating a **Fat** jar in spring boot is very easy. The part of creating a **Thin** jar requires special changes in **pom.xml** file. Let me describe both scenarios here:

In both cases, the top part will be same:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>YourApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>YourApplication</name>
    <description>Your description</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <mainClass>com.package.YourApplication.Main</mainClass>
    </properties>
```

pom.xml for fat jar:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
        your other dependencies as well...
</dependencies>

<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
      <configuration>
          <executable>true</executable>
          <excludes>
             <exclude>
                 <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                 <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
             </exclude>
          </excludes>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
      <configuration>
           <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                </manifest>
           </archive>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
<plugins>
```

The plugins are important. Because they provide specific build commands to maven.

Now, for thin jar creation:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        ...
        your other dependencies as well...
</dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>

                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
```

Here, you can see that in dependencies, tomcat provided scope is removed. Also, the plugins have changed. Executing `mvn package` then `mvn install` will generate the thin jar and copy all the dependencies outside the jar file in **lib/** folder.

I hope this helps you. :)